# Open source solver for large mixed integer programming task?

Tags: r, open-source, parallel, optimization

I'm currently using [General Algebraic Modeling System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Algebraic_Modeling_System) (GAMS), and more specifically CPLEX within GAMS, to solve a very large mixed integer programming problem. This allows me to parallelize the process over 4 cores (although I have more, CPLEX utilizes a maximum of 4 cores), and it finds an optimal solution in a relatively short amount of time.

Is there an open source mixed integer programming tool that I could use as an alternative to GAMS and CPLEX? It must be comparable in speed or faster for me to consider it. I have a preference for R based solutions, but I'm open to suggestions of all kinds, and other users may be interested in different solutions.

Comment: If you're still interested, the corresponding [CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) contains references to a large number of relevant R packages.

Answer (score 2):

Never done stuff **on that scale**, but as no-one else has jumped in yet have you seen these two papers that discuss non-commercial solutions?  Symphony and COIN-OR seem to be the dominant suggestions.

Linderoth, Jeffrey T., and Andrea Lodi. "MILP software." Wiley encyclopedia of operations research and management science (2010). [PDF version](http://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~Linderot/papers/Linderoth-Lodi-10.pdf)

Linderoth, Jeffrey T., and Ted K. Ralphs. "Noncommercial software for mixed-integer linear programming." Integer programming: theory and practice 3 (2005): 253-303. [Compares performance](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.147.5872)

Comment: Thank you for your post, but can you include some of the essential information to answer the question here? The material you linked is a great way to support the information in your answer, but this site was created to compile a great collection of questions with answers. Posts that send users elsewhere to find that information are not really considered "answers" here. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I take your point.  I thought "Symphony / COIN-OR seem to be the dominant suggestions" answered the question "is there an open source [...] alternative [...]?" - the links were for backup as to why. I did caveat that the OP's scenario is on a bigger scale than I'm used to - I cannot give any extra information from personal experience but as this is a new stackexchange site and no-one had jumped in, I thought I'd try to assist. Will delete if you think it's not helpful / an answer.